# Grothendieck's obituary. Anybody know the background behind this story?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

"In a subsequent letter to Leila Schneps, Grothendieck said he would be prepared to share his research into physics with her if she could answer one question: “What is a metre?"  "

Source: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/obituaries/11231703/Alexander-Grothendieck-obituary.html

Also, I think it comes from the AMS obituary as well.

Comment: According to Cartier, Grothendieck believed that the speed of light had been corrupted by the devil.  (See the discussion on p.26 [here](http://xahlee.info/math/i/Alexander_Grothendieck_cartier.pdf), for example.)  Given the role of the speed of light in the conventional definition of the metre, perhaps it is related to his challenge to Schneps?

Comment: Take a look at this letter https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/LGAY24691.pdf